# how can I get specific range of recors in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have following records in one of my table

```
ID(PK) PtnId  NextPtntd
1975    13  14
1976    14  15
1977    15  16
1978    16  17
1979    17  18
1980    18  19
1981    19  20
1982    20  21
1983    21  22
1984    22  23
1985    23  24
1986    24  25
1987    25  4
1988    4   26
1989    26  27
1990    27  28
1991    28  29
1992    29  30
1993    30  31
1994    31  32
1995    32  33
1996    33  34
1997    34  35
1998    35  36
1999    36  37
2000    37  38
2001    38  39
2002    39  40
2003    40
```

`Id` is primary key of table

`PtnId` is `referenceid` from other table

`NextPtnId` is next sequence from `PtnId`

Now I want to fetch records between 22 to 27 from `PtnId` column. `PtnId` columns may or may not  be in sequence of increasing order

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `BETWEEN` in your `WHERE` clause. See also [here](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-between/).

```sql
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE PtnId BETWEEN 22 AND 27;
```

**EDIT**

To include the bounds, you could do it with an `AND` statement in the `WHERE` clause.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE PtnId >= 22 AND PtnId <= 27;
```

Comment: between will eliminate value outside the range I want records in that sequence means 22,23,24,25,4,26,27

Comment: You did ask 'between', I edited the answer to include the bounds.